# Entity Framework "Invalid Column Name"

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

We have converted an existing DB to use EF, so we write classes to map to our tables.  I've added a new column, a nullable int called 'iframeVideoId'.  I mapped it with

```
public int? iframeVideoId { get; set; }
```

and when I do a search of that table, it blows up with an '

> invalid column name' error

.  This is a simple property it's not an index or related to any other table.  I tried renaming it in the DB to '`DisplayVideo`', and also making it not nullable.  Then I had

```
[Column("DisplayVideo")]
public int iframeVideoId { get; set; }
```

Now I get an error that DisplayVideo is not a valid column.  Of course I have double checked that I am pointing to the right DB, and confirmed that every DB that my code COULD point to, has this column.  I've also done a clean and rebuild all, and rebooted my machine.  What could be wrong ? This is a basic column, and it's there.  I know from past experience that if the types did not match ( they are both int ), I'd get an error related to failed conversion between types.  This makes no sense to me at all.  I do not have an edmx file to refresh, because we're writing classes to map to the DB directly

Just to add, I changed the column to a string and it makes no difference.  This is a new column, with a simple value, and EF claims it's not there.

And, I added the column to another table ( suboptimal, obviously ) and it just plain worked, immediately.  I'd still like to know why I have a table I can't add columns to in EF, though

Comment: Are you sure its in the right table and schema in that database?

Answer (score 2):

I had an error in my mapping class from copy/paste situation. As you can see, mapped *TranferredToEVP* to 3 different columns. I was getting an "invalid column name" on the last column *TranferredToGUID* but was looking for *TranferredToGUID1*. Hope this helps.

```
this.Property(t => t.TransferredToEVP).HasColumnName("TransferredToEVP");
this.Property(t => t.TransferredToEVP).HasColumnName("TransferredToName");
this.Property(t => t.TransferredToEVP).HasColumnName("TransferredToGUID");
```

Comment: Where does this go?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue like Amy Jonas had, if you happen to come across this, make sure the mapping is correct.

My code looked like this before :

```
Property(d => d.LastUpdatedOn).HasColumnName("LastUpdatedOn");
Property(d => d.LastUpdatedOn).HasColumnName("LastUpdatedBy");
```

It should be :

```
Property(d => d.LastUpdatedOn).HasColumnName("LastUpdatedOn");
Property(d => d.LastUpdatedBy).HasColumnName("LastUpdatedBy");
```

Sometimes we get too busy that we forget to look at these details.